# Error 42: Symbol Undefined _CreateWindowW@44 when trying to register non existing windows function binding

Tags: windows, d, linker-errors

I try to write simple show_window function but that which uses wide chars, there are no examples anywhere in D of that, only I could find windows creation that uses narrow-string and try now to rewrite that (I know bad english). So I'm failing even at proper registering unicode winapi bindings.

```
import core.runtime;
import core.sys.windows.windows;
import std.c.windows.windows;
pragma(lib, "gdi32.lib");
pragma(lib, "user32.lib");

struct WNDCLASSW { UINT style; WNDPROC lpfnWndProc; int cbClsExtra; int cbWndExtra; HINSTANCE hInstance; HICON hIcon; HCURSOR hCursor; HBRUSH hbrBackground; LPCWSTR lpszMenuName; LPCWSTR lpszClassName; }

extern(Windows) HWND CreateWindowW(LPCWSTR lpClassName, LPCWSTR lpWindowName, DWORD dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, HWND hWndParent, HMENU hMenu, HINSTANCE hInstance, LPVOID lpParam );

extern(Windows)
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
  HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW("wndClassName", 
   "window caption", WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND_DESKTOP, null, hInstance, null);
  return 0;
}
```

and that produces:

```
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _CreateWindowW@44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern versions of Windows do not implement CreateWindow().  It is an ancient winapi function that dates from the 1980s and has been replaced by CreateWindowEx().  In the WinUser.h SDK header, CreateWindowW is a *macro* that actually calls CreateWindowExW(), passing 0 for the extra dwExStyle argument.

You must use CreateWindowExW() instead.